# Azure DevOps - CI Build randomly starts and fails when no commits have been made [GitLab Repo/ Other Git]

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, gitlab, azure-pipelines

we've got a CI Pipeline set up and connected to an enterprise/ self-hosted Git Lab Repository via the "Other Git" option.

The Pipeline works fine when we actually commit content, it detects this and starts building as expected.

However, sometimes (normally during the night between 1-2AM) the pipeline will randomly start to build, when no commits have been made and then fail.

I think it is due to DevOps pooling our repository and failing to pool it on occasions.

The error message is below:

> An exception occurred while polling the repository. Error:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException:
>   Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Any suggestions
>   on preventing this from happening?

I've considered as a workaround using the DevOps API and GitLabs WebHooks to tell it to start building but I'm not sure if that's achievable.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: First, do you mean it is all work during the daytime, both CI, Schedule and Manual(We have a known issue in CI)? Just the error occurred on midnight? Also, does your server is behind the reverse proxy which access the server need the domain? What is the  URI scheme? HTTP? Or HTTPS? These would help with the root cause located.

Comment: We currently only have CI set up, pooling at a rate of 180s on dev branch & 400s on the master branch.  When we commit it detects this and builds normally (as expected.) If we manually build it also works fine. We do not have scheduled triggers set up. So far it has only been occurring between 1-2AM (but a small sample size of less than a week.) 

To my knowledge, the server is not behind a reserve proxy.

URI Scheme is: HTTPS:// Gitlab.Uni.ac.uk/Company/repoName.git

Comment: On our backend, the known issue is only for CI since our request connection method is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx (the public IP provided by gitlab server) while the pool method is CI. This often has issue occurred if the customer set some proxy or other irresistible factors, thus we could not connect to their gitlab server. I suggest you raise this issue on our official forum with your org name, account name, gitlab server(we often request this for a security way to protect your info). Then our product team could involved other relevant team to investigate your issue by checking our backend log.

Comment: As a work around, you can try to use API. It is using a different request connection method which would not affected by some irresistible factors.